# why does shorthand function use with a class cause "this" to be undefined?

Tags: javascript

jdfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2khtof8s/1/

```
class TestClass {
    doSomething(){
        return Promise.resolve(this.someFunction('hello'))
    }

    someFunction( testVar ){
        return testVar;
    }
}

let instance = new TestClass();

// throws error
Promise.resolve()
    .then(instance.doSomething)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);

// works
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => instance.doSomething())
    .then(console.log);

// works
Promise.resolve()
    .then(function(){return instance.doSomething()})
    .then(console.log);

// works
function someFunc(){
    return instance.doSomething();
}

Promise.resolve()
    .then(someFunc)
    .then(console.log);
```

the first Promise.resolve chain errors out with `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'someFunction' of undefined` - we can't seem to understand why, does anyone have any insight into this behaviour? As best we can tell, it seems like there shouldn't be a difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context is lost when you pass a reference to the instance's function.

```
instance.doSomething // just a reference
```

is just a reference with no context. In order to do what you are trying to do, you need to `bind` the context to the reference:

```
instance.doSomething.bind(instance)
```

---

**This might help to think of it this way:**

When you reference `instance.doSomething`, think of it as saying, "I am the `instance`, this is what `doSomething` looks like, and what I would use if you invoked me."

The difference is `referencing` vs `calling`.

Reference:

```
instance.doSomething
```

Calling: (Maintains context):

```
instance.doSomething();
```

```js
class TestClass {
  doSomething() {
    return Promise.resolve(this.someFunction('hello'))
  }

  someFunction(testVar) {
    return testVar;
  }
}

let instance = new TestClass();

// No longer throws error
Promise.resolve()
  .then(instance.doSomething.bind(instance))
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: why then do the other forms not require a bind?

Comment: @Eva Because they don't reference `this`.

Comment: @Eva, I've made some edits trying to explain the difference. But what is comes down to is that one is a reference to the function it "would" use when invoked, and the other is a call to that function still using the context.

Comment: @KevBot thanks a lot - that helps, still think it feels counter-intuitive though since I would have thought `instance` was instantiated and thus the reference would have scope :(

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for the same reason the sample below throws an error. **If you assign a function that is a property of an object to another variable, it looses its context.**

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }
  
  print() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}

const test = new Test();

test.print();      // "bar"

const standalonePrint = test.print;
standalonePrint(); // throws
```

You can solve this by **manually binding the function's context**:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}

const test = new Test();

const standalonePrint = test.print;
const boundPrint = standalonePrint.bind(test);
boundPrint(); // "bar"
```